# Перед Вами лингвистическая задача

Tags: лингвистика

Перед Вами лингвистическая задача, придуманная О.В.Федоровой. Прочитайте ее условие и выполните Задания.

Даны числительные языка санго:

pärä    0

otâ 3

mbârâmbârâ  7

balë ôko    11

balë otâ na ukü 35

balë usïö   40

balë ukü na mbârâmbârâ  57

balë miombe 80

balë miombe na miombe   88

Известно, что у одного из числительных, приведённых выше (обозначим его как Ч), числовое значение указано неправильно (обозначим это числовое значение как Х).

Задание 1. Каково правильное числовое значение числительного Ч?
Задание 2. Запишите на языке санго число Х.
Задание 3. Запишите на санго: 5, 70.
Примечание. Знаки˙˙ и ˆ обозначают особые способы произнесения гласных (так называемые тоны).

Comment: @Hulk29, Предложите, пожалуйста, свой вариант ответа на данное задание.

Comment: я всю неделю сидел у меня даже мысли не появились как ее решить

Comment: > "balë" возводит следуюшее за ним число в десятки  
  
С этим никто не спорит. Вопрос (единственный) - в другом. Почему balë ôko =/= 11. Если просто постулировать, что это десять, то я на месте проверяющего ответ бы не засчитывал. Не аргументировано.
Больше в это задаче обсуждать нечего.

Comment: С моей точки зрения, и аргументировано и доказано. Я наоборот никак не пойму, почему Вы считаете, что balë ôko может быть 11, не основываясь на данных задачи.
Могу признать Ваш вариант 11 = balë na ôko возможным в "настоящей жизни", но, так или иначе, нужен союз na для сложения десяток и едениц. Так как его нет в balë ôko, соответственно нет сложения - либо здесь всё еденицы (см. 3, 7; но это сюда явно не подходит), либо всё десятки (см. 80, 40). Можно погадать о числе 10 - balë или balë ôko, но balë ôko явно не 11.

Comment: Но если использовать условия задачи для того, чтобы больше узнать об этом языке, получается вот как. Одно число написано неправильно; это число должно быть 11, хотя-бы для того, чтобы задача имела решение. Следовательно, balë ôko НЕ МОЖЕТ равняться 11-и. Вопрос подразумевает, что такое числительное существует в языке; чем же ещё оно может быть? 10. Так что если рассматривать задачу как задачу с ответом, то ответ есть только один.

Comment: >так или иначе, нужен союз na для сложения десяток и едениц.   
  
Так вот это и есть требуемая **аргументация**, о которой не упомянули. Но пока - неполная. Почему **нужен** союз?  
  
>Одно число написано неправильно; это число должно быть 11, хотя-бы для того, чтобы задача имела решение.   
  
Предположение о существовании и единственность решения обычно не входит в число "неявно заданных". Вообще на мой вкус такие вещи сильно портят красоту задачи. Но здесь и еще есть вариант. Ошибка - 0=pärä. Ничему не противоречит, кроме одной вещи, которую я называл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 - pärä
1 - ôko
3 - otâ
4 - usïö
5 - ukü
7 - mbârâmbârâ
8 - miombe
10 - balë

~1. Каково правильное числовое значение числительного Ч?
10 - balë ôko 
~2. Запишите на языке санго число Х.
11 - balë ôko na ôko 
~3. Запишите на санго:
5 - ukü
70 - balë mbârâmbârâ

Ничего другого просто в голову не приходит.
Не понимаю, что Вы всю неделю делали.

Comment: Интересный момент! А почему мне за такой же ответ поставили "-2", и мне пришлось его убрать? Я решила, что нельзя отвечать, пока не представлен собственный вариант решения.

Comment: А зачем удаляли?
Мало ли кто двойки ставит?
Восстановить можете?

Comment: Восстанавливаю:
 balë ôko = 11 - неправильная запись, это число 10, balë ôko na ôko - так пишется число 11
Ответ:
1) Ч = balë ôko = 10,
2) Х = balë ôko na ôko = 11
3) ukü = 5, balë mbârâmbârâ = 70

А я думала, что вы минусы поставили. Вообще-то задача нетрудная. Но мне тоже стало жалко человека, который думал всю неделю.

Comment: Нет, я минусы ставлю только разве что за злостный троллинг.
Ну я не вижу, к чему тут придраться. Почему  "balë ôko"=11 - неправильно?

Comment: Потому что "balë ôko" - это 10.

Comment: А почему 10???  
  
Не... В таких задачах эти вещи надо обосновывать, а не постулировать.
Смотрите если числа 11, 12, 13 и т.д. не требуют "na" (скорее всего это союз "и") то они становятся неотличимыми от 20, 30 и т.д. Вряд ли такое возможно в реальном языке, будь он естественный или искусственный. Поэтому заключаем, что и 11 требует "na".

Comment: 13 - balë ôko na otâ, 30 - balë otâ. У нас 13: три на десять, а у них один десяток и три. У нас зо: (три десятка), а у нах десятков три

Comment: Вы о чем??? Я же говорю, такие вещи в задачах на матлингвистику надо доказывать, надо доказывать, а не постулировать.   
Но это между нами, вряд ли минусовщик думал об этом.

Comment: Согласна с Софией. "balë" возводит следуюшее за ним число в десятки. Даже в задаче, balë miombe = 80, иначе - 8•10. Вы же не скажите, что это 18. 18 было бы balë ôko na miombe (1•10 + 8). Так же и 11 (1•10 + 1) - balë ôko na ôko, потому что просто balë ôko это 1•10 = 10.